# Can't login After Signup Azure ad B2c using Custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant) to setup Azure Ad B2c. After that I [this guide](https://blog.redbaronofazure.com/?p=7751) to custom policy to use RBAC.

BUT I got an issue is: I use postman to get token

[image: img1]

Auth url: https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1a_ft_signup_signin

Token Url: https://dynatexdigital.b2clogin.com/dynatexdigital.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/toeken?p=b2c_1a_ft_signup_signin

My allication in Azure AD B2c:

[image]

This is my authentication setting in MyWebApp
[image]

When I Signup and Get Token, The response doesn't contain accesstoken:

[image]

My Custom policy:

https://github.com/wangyiwu/AzureAdPolicy

Error are:

1. I can't get access token when authentication with postman
2. I can't login, the second time when I Login by postman or run in Identity Experience Framework the message is" Username or passsword invalid. I have tried reset password in Azure|User i got message "password expired".

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get an access token, you need to specify a [scope](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/getting-an-access-token-in-azure-ad-b2c-620c0790b964).

You can't use the password reset in the portal. That's for B2C admin. accounts. You need to use the password reset / forgotten password link on the B2C login page or run a password reset policy.